# IndexOutOfRangeException ?

Tags: c#

In this following code i am receiving and out of range exception.

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int success4 = 0;
        int success6 = 0;
        int success8 = 0;
        int success10 = 0;
        int success20 = 0;
        int botch4 = 0;
        int botch6 = 0;
        int botch8 = 0;
        int botch10 = 0;
        int botch20 = 0;

        if (cbnd4.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {

            int value = 4;
            int arraySize = (int)cbnd4.SelectedIndex;
            int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arraySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 2)
                    {
                        success4++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch4++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    if(refArray[i] >= 2)
                    {
                        success4++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch4++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
           /* if (cbmd4.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
            }
            */
         if (cbnd6.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int value = 6;
            int arrySize = (int)cbnd6.SelectedIndex;
            int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arrySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {


                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 4)
                    {
                        success6++;
                    } if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch6++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 4)
                    {
                        success6++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch6++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        if (cbnd8.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int value = 8;
            int arrySize = (int)cbnd8.SelectedIndex;
            int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arrySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 5)
                    {
                        success4++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch8++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 5)
                    {
                        success4++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch8++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        if (cbnd10.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int value = 10;
            int arrySize = (int)cbnd10.SelectedIndex;
            int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arrySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 7)
                    {
                        success10++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch10++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 7)
                    {
                        success10++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch10++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        if (cbnd20.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            int value = 20;
            int arrySize = (int)cbnd20.SelectedIndex;
            int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arrySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 16)
                    {
                        success20++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                    botch20++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 7)
                    {
                        success20++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch20++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        lBotch_Result.Text = Convert.ToString(botch4 + botch6 + botch8 + botch10 + botch20);
        lSuccess_Result.Text = Convert.ToString(success4 + success6 + success8 + success10 + success20);
        MessageBox.Show("d4 successes: " +
            success4.ToString() +
            "\r\nd6 Successes: " +
            success6.ToString() +
            "\r\nd8 Successes: " +
            success8.ToString() +
            "\r\nd10 Successes: " +
            success10.ToString() +
            "\r\nd20 Successes: " +
            success20.ToString() +
            "\r\nd4 Botches: " +
            botch4.ToString() +
            "\r\nd6 Botches: " +
            botch6.ToString() +
            "\r\nd8 Botches: " +
            botch8.ToString() +
            "\r\nd10 Botches: " +
            botch10.ToString() +
            "\r\nd20 Botches: " +
            botch20.ToString());

}
```

The Out of ranged exception occurs when if(refArray[i] >= 7) and the refArray.Length contains an odd int value.

here is the Exception Output:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was
>   unhandled
>   Message="IndexOutOfRangeException"
>   StackTrace:
>          at Table_Top_Game_Dice.Form1.btnRoll_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM
>   wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM
>   wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>          at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr
>   hwnMain)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form
>   fm)
>          at Table_Top_Game_Dice.Program.Main()

any advice here would be greatly appreciated. i have been pounding my head against the wall for 5 hours trying to fix this.

oh, the refArray gets it values from the following function: (if it helps)

```
private int[] randomNumber(int value, int arraySize)
    {
        int[] randArray = new int[arraySize];
        maxValue = value;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
           randArray[i] = rand.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        }
        return randArray;
    }
```

Comment: Is this the smallest block of code that you can offer that produces the error?

Comment: That's some ugly code...there's gotta be a better way to do whatever it is you're doing. And where is minValue defined?

Comment: Smallest Block of Code? Yes, as it is the only block of code that produced the error, sorry. :-)

Ugly Code,  Absolute truth there! As this app is still an early stage of development, the code is expected, by me, to be ugly. But since this app was only started earlier today, cleaning up the code is still very much on the back burner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are obviously trying to access an array element beyond the end of the array.

The `randomNumber()`method generates an array of random numbers where the size of the array and the maximum value are independent. Therefore it might return `{ 1, 7, 13 }` if called with `arraySize` 3 and `value` 20.

Then you iterate over the array using `foreach (int i in refArray)`. In consequence there will be three iterations with `i` set to 1, then 7, and finally 13.

So if you access the array using `refArray[i]` you try to access the array elements and indexes 1, 7, and 13 and therefore get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` in the second iteration because you try to access the element at index 7 while the array contains only 3 elements.

Did you intend `for (int i = 0; i < refArray.Length; i++)` instead of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Thank your very much for you input, as this gives me a new direction to take the array Iterations. Would you have any suggested alternative method as to how to iterate through the array values?

Comment: I cannot tell from the code what you are actually trying to do. My guess is you itended `for` loops as mentioned in the last sentence of my answer. But if you really intended iterating over the elements in the array I have no clue. Maybe you could explain what the code should do.

Comment: Dice Roller - On the User interface there are several comboboxes for the user to choose what dice to roll and how many to roll. the randomnumber generator creates an array of x length where x is the number of dice the user has chosen, the maxValue parameter is passed base on the number of sides the dice has.  

the resultant array is then compared to predetermined Success values as well as predetermined Botch (epic failure) values.

then number of Successes or Botches is tallied up and displayed in a messageBox.

array values are iterated through for a comparison.

thanks for you timely reply

Comment: Then my guess seems to be correct - replace `foreach (int i in refArray)` with `for (int i = 0; i < refArray.Length; i++)`.

Comment: and I intened to use the foreach loop as described on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287602(VS.71).aspx
though i have learned never to trust every bit of info on msdn.
hence the reason i asked the question here.  thanks again for you reply

Comment: i will take you suggestion on changing to the for loop, as they do seem much more manageable, thanks again for all you time, you have been a great help.

Comment: The MSDN is correct while the example may not be the best choice and confuse some people. But now I see something I did not realize before. You can (and should) use the `foreach` loop. For this to work you just have to replace all occurences of `refArray[i]` with just `i` and all should be fine. And you should probably rename `i` to `value` or something like that because `i` implies an index.

Comment: My pleasure! (Need 15 chars...)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the error, but you are repeating a lot of code. Try to encapsulate all these code inside of each "if (cbndXX.SelectedIndex != YY) inside a function.

Something like this:

```
private void RefactorizedFunction(ComboBox cmb, ComboBox cbGame, ref int success, ref int botch, int value, int maxsuxcess)
{
    var arraySize = (int)cmb.SelectedIndex;
    int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arraySize);

    foreach (int i in refArray)    //WARNING HERE...
    {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= maxsuxcess)
                    {
                        success++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch++;
                    }
                }
                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex != 2) continue;
                if (refArray[i] >= maxsuxcess)
                {
                    success++;
                }
                if (refArray[i] == 1)
                {
                    botch++;
                }
            }
    }
```

It is not tested, and it will not solve your problem, but I'm sure your code will be easier to debug. There is other ways to improve your code, like using a dictionary or arrays instead of all these successXX and botchXX vars but... step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this piece of code able to produce an int that is equal to the size of the array and subsequently cause an outofrange exception when reading that item from the array by i.

```
int[] refArray = randomNumber(value, arraySize);
            foreach (int i in refArray)
            {

                if (cbGame.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (refArray[i] >= 2)
                    {
                        success4++;
                    }
                    if (refArray[i] == 1)
                    {
                        botch4++;
                    }
                }
```